# How do I show that $\frac xy + \frac yz + \frac zx \ge 1 + \frac {z + x}{x + y} + \frac {x + y}{z + x}$?

Tags: inequality

Show that
$$\frac xy + \frac yz + \frac zx \ge 1 + \frac {z + x}{x + y} + \frac {x + y}{z + x}$$
for $x, y, z \gt 0$.

I observed that this is a homogeneous inequality so normalization might work. I tried to set $x = 1$ or $xyz = 1$ or $x + y + z = 1$, but none of these yields a solution. How do I tackle this problem? In particular, what can I do with the term $1$? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: The RHS of your formula in the title and in the text are not identical. Which one is the good one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie What if it is cyclic, so that both are correct?

Comment: All right but if somebody gives you an answer, it is better to have the same conventions...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, it was a typo (or anything). I don't know how that comes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CS inequality in slightly different way,
$$\frac{x}y + \frac{y}z + \frac{z}x + 1  \geqslant \frac{(x+y+z+x)^2}{xy+yz+zx+x^2} = \frac{(\color{red}{x+y}\:+\:\color{blue}{z+x})^2}{(\color{red}{x+y})\cdot(\color{blue}{z+x})} = \frac{x+y}{z+x}+2 + \frac{z+x}{x+y}$$

The cyclic counterparts of the inequality can be shown similarly.

---

**Addendum:** *the inequality above is perhaps seen simplest by*
$$\frac{x}y + \frac{y}z + \frac{z}x + 1  = \frac{x^2}{xy}+\frac{y^2}{yz}+\frac{z^2}{zx}+\frac{x^2}{x^2} \geqslant \frac{(x+y+z+x)^2}{xy+yz+zx+x^2} $$
the CS form is called "[Titu's lemma](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/New%20Problems/CSNewProof/CauchySchwarzInequalityProof.pdf)" and is a useful tool to have.

Comment: Very witty ! But, two things: 1) for some (young and less young) readers, not accustomed to the tricks of the trade, I add that you take Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with vectors $(\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}},\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{z}},\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{x}},1)$ and $(\sqrt{xy},\sqrt{yz},\sqrt{zx},x)$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ 2) the case of equality can be verified to hold iff $x=y=z$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Personally I believe in giving just enough information for those interested to finish solving the problem.  Catering to all kinds of readers is a huge and largely unnecessary task, but normally if anyone has a follow up query I do answer.

Comment: I understand very well this point of view. In this case, my opinion is that we are at the limit of understandability for - say -  an undergraduate full of good will.

Comment: @JeanMarie Added a bit more, hopefully this will be enough explanation.